# countifs except the column to count changes according to drop down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a bit tricky to explain, so I'll try my best:

[image]

This is dummy data but it's good to explain my question.

I have some columns called `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` and a `Check` one.

What I did in column I, as you can see in the formula, is count everytime when `Check` is 0 AND each column `A,B,C and D` take the value in `B1`, which is a drop down list with `Y, N and * (to grab all possible occurrences).` As you can see in I5, in Column A there is only 1 occurrence that had check = 0 and it's value in A is N.

I was thinking it would be good to, instead of having a cell for the Count for each column, creating a second drop down list to select what column I'm interested in. I created this drop down list on `B13`.

As I hardcoded in this snippet, in this case when `Outcomes` = N and `Column` = A, the Generic count should be 1.

How can I do this? I've tried LOOKUP, MATCH, INDIRECT, ADDRESS, INDEX, etc, but couldn't make it work. Haven't found any tutorial that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX($B$4:$E$11,0,MATCH($B$13,$B$3:$E$3,0)),$B$1,$F$4:$F$11,0)
```

[image]

Comment: That works great! I think I found why it wasn't working for me: if I don't do the index/match, I can do generic $F:$F on the last term and it works fine, however when I include the index/match I have to specify the range. Do you have any idea why this might be happening? I'm curious

Comment: I'm asking this because my data might get larger in time, how can I make sure the formulas automatically adjust to the length?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(INDEX($B$4:$E$1040000,0,MATCH($B$13,$B$3:$E$3,0)),$B$1,$F$4:$F$1040000,0)` will do it. But You will need to move the `$B$13` to another cell.  It cannot be in the column being referenced.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, maybe something along the lines of:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:E3=B13)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,B4:E11)))*(F4:F11=0))
```